# NSIS RadioButton How to group

Tags: nsis

There are multiple RadioButton controls in the NSIS interface configuration file ini, how to group them, using the group attribute?How does this property set the value?How to write? help me！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says so right in the [Install Options documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/InstallOptions/Readme.html):

GROUP:

> Add this flag to the first control of a group of controls to group them. Grouping controls allows you to create multiple groups of radio button and makes keyboard navigation using arrow keys easier.

NOTABSTOP:

> Do not stop on the control when the user pressed the Tab key. Add NOTABSTOP to all controls of a group except the first one to allow navigation between groups with the Tab key.

```
RequestExecutionLevel User
OutFile "test.exe"

Function .onInit
; Writing out the .ini manually here to keep the example in one source file
InitPluginsDir
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" Settings NumFields 4
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Type RadioButton
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Text G1:Radio1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Flags GROUP
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" State 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Left 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Right -1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Top 0
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 1" Bottom 10
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Type RadioButton
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Text G1:Radio2
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Flags NOTABSTOP
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Left 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Right -1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Top 10
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 2" Bottom 20
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Type RadioButton
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Text G2:Radio1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Flags GROUP
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Left 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Right -1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Top 50
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 3" Bottom 60
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Type RadioButton
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Text G2:Radio2
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Flags NOTABSTOP
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" State 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Left 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Right -1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Top 60
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini" "Field 4" Bottom 70
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd

Page Custom MyPage
Page InstFiles

Function MyPage
InstallOptions::dialog "$PluginsDir\MyPage.ini"
Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```